# How to compare two lists and return another list with values ​that are identical? - Flutter and Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have two lists of returning IDs. I want to compare the two and return a new list with the IDs that appear in both. Then, save these values ​​in a new collection in Firebase.

What is the best way to do this? I found several similar topics but none helped.

I tried to use the intersection(), but it doesn't return anything at the end. That's how I'm getting the two lists:

```
List<Users> followingList;
List<Users> followersList;

  Future<List<Users>> _getFollowersUsers() async {
    Firestore db = Firestore.instance;

    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await db
        .collection('followers')
        .document(_userId)
        .collection("userFollowers")
        .getDocuments();

    List<Users> followersList = [];
    for (DocumentSnapshot item in querySnapshot.documents) {
      var data = item.data;
      if (data["id"] == _userId) continue;

      Users user = Users();
      user.name = data["name"];
      user.photoUrl = data["imageUrl"];
      user.username = data["username"];
      user.id = data["id"];
      user.bio = data["bio"];

      followersList.add(user);
    }

    return followersList;
  }

  Future<List<Users>> _getFollowingUsers() async {
    Firestore db = Firestore.instance;

    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await db
        .collection('following')
        .document(_userId)
        .collection("userFollowing")
        .getDocuments();

    List<Users> followingList = [];
    for (DocumentSnapshot item in querySnapshot.documents) {
      var data = item.data;
      if (data["id"] == _userId) continue;

      Users user = Users();
      user.name = data["name"];
      user.photoUrl = data["imageUrl"];
      user.username = data["username"];
      user.id = data["id"];
      user.bio = data["bio"];

      followingList.add(user);
    }

    return followingList;
  }

  getFinalList() {
    var finalList =
        followingList.toSet().intersection(followersList.toSet()).toList();

    print(finalList);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check item by item in a for and adding to another list,

```
 getFinalList() {
    List<User> result = [];
    followingList.forEach((aElement) {
      User value =
          followersList.firstWhere((bElement) => bElement.id == aElement.id, orElse: () => null);
      if (value != null) {
        result.add(value);
      }
    });
    print(result);
  }
```

Comment: The lists I am getting in the Future functions are working but it seems that the values ​​are not being saved here:

  List<Users> followingList;
  List<Users> followersList;

Comment: This code is for getting the common elements on the lists, but you need to make sure the futures are done before calling it.

Comment: I was missing that, now it works. Thanks!